# Cancel all pending Intents set in alarm manager in android, but not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am adding alarm through service and i m also creating a broadcast to cancel all the alarms(Pending Intents) with in the same service when i m pressing signout i want to unregistere all the alarms so i m calling that broadcast receiver, but still that alarm is still firing. i also tried the same thing with storing pending Intent object into an array list & then the same object to remove alarm, Here is my code..

```
public class AddReminderService extends Service {
    ArrayList<Integer> intentArray;
    ArrayList<pendingIntent> pendingIntentArray;
    AlarmManager alarmManager,CancelalarmManager;
    ArrayList<Bundle> bundleArray;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerReceiver(cancelAlarms, new IntentFilter("com.x.y.ReminderAlerts.AlarmCancel"));
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        if (intent.hasExtra("ReminderDetails")) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> entries = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) intent
                    .getSerializableExtra("ReminderDetails");
            Log.v("AddReminderService", "OnStart entries size()"+entries.size());
            addReminder(entries);
        }
    }

    private void addReminder(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> entries) 
    {
        intentArray= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        bundleArray= new ArrayList<Bundle>();
        pendingIntentArray= new ArrayList<pendingIntent>();
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++) {
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            setAlarm(i,alarmTime, activity, stringStartTime, stringEndTime, ReminderSysID);
        }
    }

    private void setAlarm(int position,long alarmTime, String actvity, String startTime,
        String endTime, String ReminderSysID) {
        if (alarmTime > (new Date()).getTime()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.setAction("com.x.y.ReminderAlerts.ALARMRECIEVER");
            intent.addCategory("com.x.y.ReminderAlerts.ALARMRECIEVER");
            Bundle c = new Bundle();
            c.putString("Actvity", actvity);
            c.putString("Start_tim", startTime);
            c.putString("Endtime", ReminderSysID);
            c.putInt("ReminderSysID", Integer.parseInt(ReminderSysID));
            intent.putExtras(c);
            bundleArray.add(c);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), Integer.parseInt(ReminderSysID), intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            pendingIntentArray.add(pendingIntent);
            intentArray.add(Integer.parseInt(ReminderSysID));       
            Log.i("intentArray alarm id",Integer.parseInt(ReminderSysID)+"" );
            Log.e("registerReciever",""+pendingIntent); 
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
    public BroadcastReceiver cancelAlarms = new BroadcastReceiver() {   
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("cancelalarmreciever","On alarm cancel reciever");
            if(intentArray.size()>0){
                for(int i=0; i<intentArray.size(); i++){
                    Log.i("cancelAlarms alarm id",intentArray.get(i)+"" );
                    Intent tempIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                    intent.setAction("com.x.y.ReminderAlerts.ALARMRECIEVER");
                    intent.addCategory("com.x.y.ReminderAlerts.ALARMRECIEVER");
                    intent.putExtras(bundleArray.get(i));
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                        getApplicationContext(), intentArray.get(i), tempIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    Log.v("registerReciever",""+pendingIntent);
                ///.cancel();
                    Log.v("cancelalarmreciever index","On alarm cancel reciever"+intentArray.get(i));
                    CancelalarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    CancelalarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntentArray.get(i));
                    Log.v("cancelalarmreciever pendint intent","On alarm cancel reciever"+pendingIntentArray.get(i));
                }
            }
            intentArray.clear();
            pendingIntentArray.clear();
            unregisterReceiver(cancelAlarms);
            stopSelf();
        }   
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs a lot of love :-(

Anyway, when you try to cancel the alarms in `onReceive()` you do this:

```
Intent tempIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.setAction("com.x.y.ReminderAlerts.ALARMRECIEVER");
intent.addCategory("com.x.y.ReminderAlerts.ALARMRECIEVER");
intent.putExtras(bundleArray.get(i));
```

You probably means to set the ACTION, CATEGORY and extras on `tempIntent`, like this:

```
Intent tempIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
tempIntent .setAction("com.x.y.ReminderAlerts.ALARMRECIEVER");
tempIntent .addCategory("com.x.y.ReminderAlerts.ALARMRECIEVER");
tempIntent .putExtras(bundleArray.get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight wrong in the code. Don't try it with the same object. create a different object.

Comment: i tried with different object as well but still alarm is firing